# Installing RestKit.FrameWork on ios application libRestKit.a file missing, its in RedColor?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, static-libraries, restkit

I am trying to add/install  `RestKit.FramWork` on ios application based on the [documentaion](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x)

After Target Dependency has been configured I am trying to add  Link Binary With Libraries.
if   i am adding `libRestKit.a` this file was missing. its shows as red color.

[image]

Comment: What happens after you try to build you project? It is normal for just added library that it has no built their products, thus, they are not yet available in filesystem and appears red in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

When adding libraries in the new Xcode, you sometimes have to drag/drop the files into your project's directory in finder and restart Xcode. After you've restarted Xcode, drag/drop the files from the finder window (your project's directory) into your Xcode project explorer and check the little "add files" box. That's all I got.

Comment: 1) delete all red files from your project 2) close Xcode 3) add them to the directory in finder 4) reopen Xcode and drag/drop the files from your projects directory (the ones you just added) into your project explorer 5) re-add the libraries. That really should just work.

Comment: I did this steps so many times, the same problem comimg each time and one more error "Use of UnDeclaered identifier 'NSOrderedSet' did you mean 'NSOrderedSame'"